# Opencv framerate is getting lower after some time

Tags: c++, opencv, capture, frame-rate

I´m working on project which will track object on 4 cameras so i need to read frames from 4 sources at once. I tried it like this and got like 15 fps with my analysis.

```
cv::Mat uloz_analyzuj(cv::VideoCapture capture, cv::Mat Feed{
    capture.read(Feed);

    return Feed;
}

    std::thread t1([&capture, &cameraFeed, &gpuFeed]() {
        cameraFeed = uloz_analyzuj(capture, cameraFeed);
    });

    std::thread t2([&capture2, &cameraFeed2, &gpuFeed2]() {
        cameraFeed2 = uloz_analyzuj(capture2, cameraFeed2);
    });

    std::thread t3([&capture3, &cameraFeed3, &gpuFeed3]() {
        cameraFeed3 = uloz_analyzuj(capture3, cameraFeed3);
    });

    std::thread t4([&capture4, &cameraFeed4, &gpuFeed4]() {
        cameraFeed4 = uloz_analyzuj(capture4, cameraFeed4);
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
```

So i tried different method to achieve more fps because i knew that this was bottlenecking part in my project and I achieved significantly more fps (around 24). But after some time maybe 30 seconds i have only 40 % of fps ending at 8 fps.

```
    std::thread threadik(uloz_analyzuj, &capture, &Feed);
    threadik.detach();
    std::thread threadik2(uloz_analyzuj, &capture2, &Feed2);
    threadik2.detach();
    std::thread threadik3(uloz_analyzuj, &capture3, &Feed3);
    threadik3.detach();
    std::thread threadik4(uloz_analyzuj, &capture4, &Feed4);
    threadik4.detach();
```

and method looks like this:

```
void uloz_analyzuj(cv::VideoCapture *capture, cv::Mat *Feed) {
    while (1) {
        mtxCam.lock();
        *capture >> *Feed;
        mtxCam.unlock();
    }
}
```

Have you ever seen behavior like this? How can I fix it to perform as it should?

Comment: Try watching the memory (with `top` or a Process Monitor) to see if it is leaking memory and starving itself.

Comment: Tahnks for reply. It seems like memory usage is getting higher. How  to avoid it?

Comment: I am not sure what folks use these days - probably `valgrind` - though I am happy to be corrected and learn myself. Or publish your code. Or search through it for memory allocations that are not correspondingly freed up afterwards.

Comment: I realized I created threads inside a loop so I put it outside and it works like charm. Thanks for your advice and time.

Comment: Excellent - good luck with your project!